# Can anyone give an example for this theorem related to planar graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

**Theorem**:

> Let $G$ be a connected planar graph with $p$ vertices and $q$ edges, where $p\geq 3$. Then $q\leq3p-6$.

**Proof**:
Let $r$ be the  number of regions in a planar representation of $G$. By Euler's formula:

> $p-q+r=2$

The **sum** of the degrees of the regions equals $2q$ . But each regions has degree $3$ or more, hence

> $2q\geq3r$.

Question is, from where does the inequality come from?

No matter how many **connected, planar** graphs I draw, I always get $2q = 3r$. Can someone give me a graph or a case where $2q>3r$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

any planar connected graph that has a region with degree 4 or more, and without pendant nodes

---

Note: "The sum of the degrees of the regions equals $2q$" is false, because you could have some edge that belongs to only one region (for example in the [star graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28graph_theory%29)).

But it's true that the sum of the degrees of the regions is greater or equal to $3r$, and less or equal to $2q$, so the theorem is still correct.

Comment: In other words, by reading the proof carefully we note that "each region has degree $3$ **or more**" is the reason for the inequality.

Comment: I didn't say there was anything needing a fix :) - "... equals $2q$" is true with suitable counting. E.g., in the star graoh with $e$ edges, the region may be viewed as a degenerate $2n$-gon.

Comment: The thing is that you may want to use the Euler's formula, so $r$ must be the real number of regions

Comment: @Exodd: In that case what is the degree of the region of a star graph since there are no cycles or closed walks that border the region?

Comment: @Sidsec9 is the number od edges that belong to that region

Answer (score 2):

The cycle $C_n$ for $n\geq 4$. Then $q=n$ but $r=2$ and certainly $2n>6$.